# Function doesn't work when moved to global

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

In my Ionic app, I want to download certain files. The `TransferObject` should be accessible on every page, so I moved my download function to my global variables. Note that the download worked just fine when it was not in globals.
Here's what I have:

**providers/global/global.ts**

```
import {Injectable, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
import { Transfer, FileUploadOptions, TransferObject } from '@ionic-native/transfer';
import { File, Entry } from '@ionic-native/file';

@Injectable()
export class Global {

public progress_locatie1: string;
public progress_locatie2: string;

public progressbar_locatie1=false;
public progressbar_locatie2=false;

public downloadbutton_locatie1=true;
public downloadbutton_locatie2=true;

public playbutton_locatie1=false;
public playbutton_locatie2=false;

constructor(public ref: ChangeDetectorRef, public file: File, public transfer: Transfer) {
    this.progress_locatie1 = '0';
    this.progress_locatie2 = '0';
     }
public fileTransfer_locatie1: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();
public fileTransfer_locatie2: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();

setProgress(location, value) {
    this['progress_'+location]=value;
    this.ref.detectChanges();
}

getProgress(location) {
    return this['progress_'+location];
}

setStatusOfObject(object,location, value)
{
    this[object+'_'+location]=value;
}

getStatusOfObject(object,location)
{
    return this[object+'_'+location];
}

startDownload(locatie)
{
    this.setStatusOfObject('downloadbutton',locatie,false);
    this.setStatusOfObject('progressbar',locatie,true);

    this['fileTransfer_' + locatie].download('https://someurl.com/'+locatie+'.mp4', this.file.dataDirectory + 'path/to/downloads/'+locatie+'.mp4').then((entry) => {
        console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());

        this.setStatusOfObject('progressbar',locatie,false);
        this.setStatusOfObject('playbutton',locatie,true);

    }, (error) => {
        console.log('error');
        console.log(error);
    });

    this['fileTransfer_' + locatie].onProgress(progressEvent => {
        if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
            console.log("### Download percentage ###: "+(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total));
            this.setProgress(locatie,Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100));
        } else {
        }
    });
}

cancelDownload(locatie)
{
    this.setStatusOfObject('downloadbutton',locatie,true);
    this.setStatusOfObject('progressbar',locatie,false);
    this.setStatusOfObject('playbutton',locatie,false);
    this.setProgress(locatie,"0");
    this['fileTransfer_' + locatie].abort();
}

}
```

**pages/somepage/somepage.ts**

```
import {Global} from '../../providers/global/global';
export class SomePage {
constructor(private global: Global) {
}

downloadnative(locatie)
{
    this.global.startDownload(locatie);
}

cancel_download(locatie)
{
    this.global.cancelDownload(locatie);
}
}
```

**pages/somepage/somepage.html**

```
<button ion-button full color="light" *ngIf="global.getStatusOfObject('downloadbutton','locatie1')" (tap)="downloadnative('locatie1')">Download</button>
```

When I press the download button, nothing happens. No console output, nothing.
Everything worked fine when the download part was in `pages/somepage.ts`, but as I said, I want to access the `TransferObject` on other pages too.

Extra info: the `startDownload` function itself is called, but the download doesn't start.

Comment: Consider providing http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve with stubbed Ionic stuff . If you cannot debug Ionic application, you're on your own with it. It's hard to believe that you have nothing in the console. For starters, you cannot inject ChangeDetectorRef to services, this will throw injection error.

Comment: `ChangeDetectorRef` doesn't throw an error. When the download function was on somepage.ts, setProgress whas already in global.ts to access the progress on different pages. It would only work with `detectChanges()`. There are things in the console, I meant there's nothing about an error in the console. Putting a console.log in the startDownload function for example would correctly print to the console.

Comment: ChangeDetectorRef  exists only within components. If it doesn't cause an error, this means that Global isn't module provider but component provider. You should specify how you define and use it. And most likely this is terribly wrong, because ChangeDetectorRef is individual for each component, while you expect Global to be a singleton. Again, MCVE is necessary. You can't expect a good answer for the question in its current state. This is total guesswork.

Comment: @binoculars I have to agree with estus. Where do you provide this service for example? In the app.module?

Comment: @echonax yes, `Global` is provided in the app.module.

Comment: @estus you were right, `Global` was provided by accident in app.components too. I removed it, and `ChangeDetectorRef` started throwing an error as expected. So I removed `ChangeDetectorRef` from gobal, which removed the error. Didn't solve my problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after a lot of trial and error.
Changing this:

```
public fileTransfer_locatie1: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();
public fileTransfer_locatie2: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();
```

to:

```
public fileTransfer_locatie1: TransferObject;
public fileTransfer_locatie2: TransferObject;
...
startDownload(locatie)
{
  this['fileTransfer_' + locatie] = this.transfer.create();
  ...
}
```

fixed my problem.